# Went from a plain silverlight app to XNA app, SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current is null

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna

I've had this Silverlight application where in the end needed some more rendering power, so I've tried to convert the project to a Silverlight/XNA project. It builds and runs, but when I navigate to `GamePage.xaml` where the XNA is it says:

> "`SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current` is `null` in the `OnNavigatedTo` function."

It is really weird, as I just copied source from a blank project and created the correct support libs, and referenced the same libs. Did I forget something somewhere? Is `SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current` initiated somewhere?